# question about symmetric idempotent matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

$P$ is symmetric and idempotent, $Q\ge 0$ i.e. $Q$ is s.p.d.
and $I-P-Q\ge 0$, how to prove $PQ=QP=0$?

can we get $PQ\le 0$ from $I-P-Q\ge 0$ by left multiply $P$?
If it is right, then since $P,Q$ are s.p.d, so $PQ$ have non-negative eigenvalues, hence $PQ=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may begin with $-PQP=P(I-P-Q)P\succeq0$. (So, you need not only left multiplication, but also right multiplication by $P$.) Alternatively, perform a change of basis so that $P$ becomes $I_r\oplus0_{(n-r)\times(n-r)}$, where $r$ is the rank of $P$.